# Is there a window.onclose or onwindow.close javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a "window.onclose" or "onwindow.close" on javascript that detects when a window is closing. A code like this:

```
window.onclose
```

or a code like this:

```
onwindow.close
```

Is there  code like that on javascript that will detect when a window is closing?

Comment: As a tip for future searches, `onwindow.close` is an unlikely name: it would require there to be an object called `onwindow`, which wouldn't make much sense. On the other hand, knowing that there is an object called `window`, and that events are properties beginning `on`, looking for things beginning `window.on...` would be a good bet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to detect that it is about to close use:

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

See MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 2):

There is [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload).

There is more [information about the unload event here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/unload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/unload).